Property 'vector' does not exist on type 'Layer' in HERE Maps API for JavaScript (React - TypeScript/Vite bundler)
I'm trying to integrate a map location API using HERE Maps API @here/maps-api-for-javascript latest version("@here/maps-api-for-javascript": "^1.54.1") in a Reactjs project. App created with vite bundler, and uses TypeScript for development.
When I run npm run build, I get the error: "Property 'vector' does not exist on type 'Layer'.ts(2339)" in the below code:
const newMap = new H.Map(
        mapRef.current,
        defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
        {
          pixelRatio: 2,
          zoom: 17,
          center: position,
        }
      );

can HERE Developer Support help?
If you'd like me to provide more context, I'd be more than happy to do so, please.
I've tried several configurations including using type assertion as below:
const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers(512,  320) as H.map.layer.Layer

